# Rename Sim Card Programatically in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am looking for a solution to rename a sim card name programatically. we can do it in android 5.0 by opening settings then go to sim cards select the sim card and then click on SIM name, give a name to it and save, but I need to rename it programatically. is there any solution exist for this?
Please help me out.

Comment: is it for dual sim ?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Yes its for dual sim

Comment: There is no sdk support for dual sim in Android, as it is not supported in official sdk.

Comment: You can ask device manufacturer for their sdk if available.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Can we achieve this using NDK by writing some native code for it?

Comment: Possibly yes, Reflection can also help but thats not recommended.